# How can i extract nested objects from json in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jquery code extracts gets the josn from url and put in html table

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('/api/students/2/?format=json', function(data) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<tr><td>' +key+'</td><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
        });

        $(items.join('')).appendTo('table');

    });

});
```

This loads the first level of objects fine but i have  many nested levels.
I have all the data inside json. currently it shows `object[]` but i want to shows its sub elements like below

like

`studnets` have `semester` then `subjects` and then `assignments`

i want to display them nested inside the main table within own tables like this

```
<table>
<tr><td>student name  </td></tr>
          <tr><td>semesters  
             <table>
                   <tr><td> subjects 
                                <table><tr><td> Assigments
```

so that i can get the detail view of whole data in one page.

This looks like buggy but i am not able to find better way of represeting student data

EDIT

sample json data

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John",
    "terms": [
        {
            "id": 26,
            "name":"summer"
            "date": "2013-02-18",
            "subjects_set": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "math",
                    "gb_type": [ ],
                    "assignment_set": [
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "assignment_level_1",
                            "documents": [ ]
                        }
                    ]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your `json` data structure?

Comment: Is the outermost data (student) an array or an object? Are you trying to display course info of multiple students or just one?

Comment: just one student , but then terms, subjects , assignment can be multiple

Comment: You might find this library useful: http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `html` output/structure you're trying to achieve is a bit complicated, i'll leave the html string appending/concatenation part up to you. As for accessing the `json` values, refer to the code below:

```
$.getJSON('/api/students/2/?format=json', function (data) {
    var items = [];    
    //To get student name
    var studentName = data.name;    
    var semester, subject, assignment;
    $.each(data.terms, function () {
        semester = this;
        //to get semester name and date
        var semesterName = semester.name,
            semesterDate = semester.date;
        $.each(semester.subjects_set, function(){
            subject = this;
            //to get subject name
            var subjectName = subject.name;                
            $.each(subject.assignment_set, function(){
                assignment = this;
                //to get assignment name
                var assignmentName = assignment.name;     
            });
        });        
    });
    //$(items.join('')).appendTo('table');
});
```

You need to write the html string concatenation code within the `$.each` section. However, if you have difficulties with the string concatenation, just show me the desired `html` output and i can help with that as well.